# Are the disciples Bartholomew (Synoptics) and Nathanael (John) the same person?

Tags: gospels, onomastics, apostle

The Synoptic Gospels refer to one of the 12 disciples as Bartholomew, and regularly pair him with Philip:

Matthew 10:

> 2 Now the names of the twelve apostles are these; The first, Simon,
> who is called Peter, and Andrew his brother; James the son of Zebedee,
> and John his brother;
>
> 3 **Philip, and Bartholomew**; Thomas, and Matthew the publican; James the
> son of Alphæus, and Lebbæus, whose surname was Thaddæus;
>
> 4 Simon the Canaanite, and Judas Iscariot, who also betrayed him.

Mark 3:

> 14 And he ordained twelve, that they should be with him, and that he
> might send them forth to preach,
>
> ...
>
> 16 And Simon he surnamed Peter;
>
> 17 And James the son of Zebedee, and John the brother of James; and he
> surnamed them Boanerges, which is, The sons of thunder:
>
> 18 And Andrew, and **Philip, and Bartholomew**, and Matthew, and
> Thomas, and James the son of Alphæus, and Thaddæus, and Simon the
> Canaanite,
>
> 19 And Judas Iscariot,

Luke 6:

> 13 And when it was day, he called unto him his disciples: and of them
> he chose twelve, whom also he named apostles;
>
> 14 Simon, (whom he also named Peter,) and Andrew his brother, James
> and John, **Philip and Bartholomew**,
>
> 15 Matthew and Thomas, James the son of Alphæus, and Simon called
> Zelotes,
>
> 16 And Judas the brother of James, and Judas aIscariot, which also was
> the traitor.

John never refers to Bartholomew, but does refer to Nathanael (never mentioned in the Synoptics) as one who was called by Philip (see John 1:45-48) and a colleague of Peter, James, John, and Thomas (John 21:2).

Are Bartholomew & Nathanael the same person?

Answer (score 1):

Note the comments from Thayer's lexicon on the name (and person) Ναθαναήλ:

> Ναθαναήλ, ὁ (נְתַנְאֵל, gift of God), Nathanael, an intimate disciple
> of Jesus: John 1:45-49 (); . lie is commonly thought to be identical
> with Bartholomew, because as in John 1:45 () he is associated with
> Philip, so in Matthew 10:3; Mark 3:18; Luke 6:14 Bartholomew is;
> Nathanael, on this supposition, was his personal name, and Bartholomew
> a title derived from his father (see Βαρθολομαῖος). But in Acts 1:13
> Thomas is placed between Philip and Bartholomew; (see B. D. under the
> word ). Späth in the Zeitschr. f. wissensch. Theologie, 1868, pp.
> 168ff, 309ff (again 1880, pp. 78ff) acutely but vainly tries to prove
> that the name was formed by the Fourth Evangelist symbolically to
> designate 'the disciple whom Jesus loved' (see Ἰωάννης, 2).

This is well-known.  Note the comments from Strong's lexicon:

> Nathanael, of Cana in Galilee, an early disciple, probably to be
> identified with Bartholomew.

Now notice the comments of the NAS exhaustive concordance:

> Nathanael (probably the same as Bartholomew, see NG0918)